# How to calculate CREATE2 address in golang?

Tags: golang, create2

I have a factory pattern smart contract that creates other smart-contracts by cloning the master smart contract via Minimal Proxy Contract and CREATE2 opcode. What is the proper way to calculate CREATE2 final address in golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go-ethereum` have a function for this https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto?tab=doc#CreateAddress2

```go
func CreateAddress2(b common.Address, salt [32]byte, inithash []byte) common.Address
```

Where `b` is the factory, `salt` the salt used, `inithash` is your init data hash.

You can calculate `inithash` like that

```go
func getInithash(contractABI, contractBin string, params ...interface{}) []byte {
    parsed, _ := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(contractABI))
    packedArguments, _ := parsed.Pack("", params...) // constructor params

    initData := append(common.FromHex(contractBin), packedArguments...)
    return crypto.Keccak256(initData)
}
```